# How to override the NameID value in SAMLAuthenticationProvider?

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm using Spring Security SAML 1.0.1. My application uses this XML to configure the `SAMLAuthenticationProvider` bean :

```xml
<!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
<b:bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
    <b:property name="userDetails">
        <b:bean class="eu.ueb.acem.services.auth.SamlAuthenticationUserDetailsService"/>
    </b:property>
    <b:property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false"/>
</b:bean>
```

The class "SamlAuthenticationUserDetailsService" implements the `loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential)` method. If the user doesn't exist in the database, it is created.

```java
@Override
public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    logger.info("entering loadUserBySAML({})", credential);
    String userID = credential.getNameID().getValue();
    logger.info("{} is logged in", userID);
    Map<String, String> mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("eduPersonAffiliation", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("eduPersonPrincipalName", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("eduPersonPrimaryAffiliation", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("supannEtablissement", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("supannEntiteAffectationPrincipale", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("supannOrganisme", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("displayName", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("mail", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("givenName", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("sn", null);
    mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put("uid", null);

    for (Attribute attribute : credential.getAttributes()) {
        logger.info("attribute friendly name={}", attribute.getFriendlyName());
        if (mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.containsKey(attribute.getFriendlyName())) {
            // We set the values of the property
            for (XMLObject attributeValueXMLObject : credential.getAttribute(attribute.getName()).getAttributeValues()) {
                logger.info("We care about this attribute, getAttributeValue={}", getAttributeValue(attributeValueXMLObject));
                mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.put(attribute.getFriendlyName(), getAttributeValue(attributeValueXMLObject));
            }
        }
        else {
            logger.info("We don't care about this attribute");
        }
    }
    Person user = usersService.getUser(mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.get("eduPersonPrincipalName"));
    user.setLogin(mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.get("eduPersonPrincipalName"));
    user.setEmail(mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.get("mail"));
    user.setName(mapOfAttributesFriendlyNamesAndValues.get("displayName"));
    user.setAdministrator(true);
    user = usersService.updatePerson(user);
    logger.info("leaving loadUserBySAML");
    return loadUserByUser(user);
}

private UserDetails loadUserByUser(Person targetUser) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Roles
    if (targetUser.isAdministrator()) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    else {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    return new User(targetUser.getLogin(), targetUser.getPassword(),
            true, // enabled
            true, // account not expired
            true, // credentials not expired
            true, // account not locked
            authorities);
}
```

I have the following behaviour :

- I request a page on my SP which requires authentication
- I'm redirected to the IDP (would be better to the Discovery Service)
- The IDP correctly returns the credential
- My `loadUserBySAML` method is called
- If the user doesn't exist, it is created in the database with a login equal to its email address
- The requested page loads and the created User is not reused, instead, a new User is created with a login equal to the value of `credential.getNameID().getValue()` (e.g. "_246558c0d7c514447292d750df577b6b").

**Question** : how can I set the "NameID" attribute of the credential to be the e-mail address?

I have read multiple times the section "9.4 Authentication object" of [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-authentication-object) but I still don't understand how to tell Spring Security that my `UserDetails` object should be referenced with the email address and not with the NameID value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem might be that `SAMLAuthenticationProvider` by default always uses `NameID`, even when `UserDetails` gets returned from the `SAMLUserDetailsService`. It's done so for backwards compatibility with previous versions, although I'm considering changing it to avoid confusion.

In order to use values returned from your `UserDetails` set property `forcePrincipalAsString` to false on bean `SAMLAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: I think that I already set the property, as shown in the posted configuration.

Comment: Problem is solved this morning! This was caused by the refresh delay of the SP metadata in the Renater identity federation. I'm so happy!